# Lamp web server (trusting ssl certificates)

Tags: php, ios, ssl

So this may be a little broad, but I will be as specific as possible with what I am working on.

Currently I am developing an iPhone app using swift 3.  This app performs a post request to a php file located on a lamp server that is on a different network.  The server is primarily being used to simply take the data sent from the app and store it into some mysql tables.

Currently, I am doing this.

```
func sendToServer(firstEntry: String, secondEntry: String, serverAddr: String){
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let uid = firstEntry
    let gender = secondEntry
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: serverAddr)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "UID=\(uid)&Gender=\(gender)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
```

This sends the data over like it should.  But I would like to see if anyone can answer these couple questions.

Is there a way to get a trusted certificate without having a domain name?

If I do it this way will there be issues with the app getting rejected for this?

Thanks

Comment: Your questions do not make sense, sorry. Even _if_ you could get such a certificate, what use is it? No client would be interested in it. From a technical point of view a https connection without valid host name you actually control does not make sense. The whole point of a signed, so trusted certificate is that it allows the client to guarantee that the server it connects to actually is the intended one. That requires a host name the certificate is signed to be issued for. Without such host name you can sign a certificate however you like, there is nothing to trust.

Comment: The question is: why don't you simply purchase a domain name (a few Euros a year) and get a free signed and trusted certificate for that? You can even get multiple ones for free for all host names you like to use under your domain name. Is that really too expensive?

Comment: We could purchase a domain name.  I guess I will have to look into that.  We are just connecting to with the server's public ip.

Comment: You cannot get a certificate signed for an IP address. That is not how things work.

Comment: And, btw, for a productive service you definitely want to use a host name for the connection, _not_ a raw IP address. Later, once you need the flexibility you get from that, you will be grateful that you did not try to outsmart yourself but listener to the experience of millions of other people operating services ;-)

Comment: Ok so if I just purchase the domain name, then I can get get the signed trusted certificate for that?  Currently I just get warnings about a self signed certificates.  Once I get the trusted certificate after purchasing the domain name will I have to modify any code in the app or since its trusted I won't have anything to worry about?  Thanks for the help by the way.  I appreciate it.

Comment: You cannot get a signed certificate for a domain name. As said above you can only get a signed certificate for a host name. One certificate per host name. Or a "wildcard certificate" for all possible host names under a given domain name, those are expensive though and I do not see any point in that any more. Take a look at the "LetsEncrypt" project: you get free signed and trusted certificates from them for any host name you have control over. Typical host names would be `www.example.com` and `api.example.com` for your domain `example.com`. You can also use `example.com` as a host name btw.